# Show search result on SearchPopupAutoDropdown

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

I am designing a control similar to Visual Studio's [NavigateTo](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsdata/2009/07/02/tips-using-navigate-to-for-search-in-visual-studio/).

Following instructions for [Adding Search to a Tool Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266761.aspx), I have the control setup and I want to show search results as we type. So:

```
public void ProvideSearchSettings(IVsUIDataSource pSearchSettings)
{
    Utilities.SetValue(pSearchSettings, SearchSettingsDataSource.PropertyNames.SearchPopupAutoDropdown, true);
}
```

The auto popup drops down when I type something.
I get search results using own logic say

```
string[] searchResults = GetResults(SearchQuery.SearchString);
```

But how do I show those results on the dropdown? Unable to figure out if there is a parameter somewhere I can pass for it to be shown. The results do not necessarily need to be string array.

Any help or ideas?

Comment: Do you mean you want to show searchResults on the the dropdown whatever you type any words?

Comment: Yes. Search based on the word typed in.

Comment: Is the variable named searchResults the result filtered by the word typed in?

Comment: Yes, that is an example abstracting any search logic. I already have search results as I can get the text typed in and use it. But just unable to show the results.